# REDCap in Ubuntu - Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, domdocument, redcap

REDCap crashed due to an unexpected PHP fatal error!

```
Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in
 redcap_v14.3.0/Classes/RenderProjectList.php:827 Stack trace: #0
 redcap_v14.3.0/Classes/RenderProjectList.php(750): RenderProjectList::renderProjectsGrid()
 #1 redcap_v14.3.0/Home/index.php(523): RenderProjectList->renderprojects() #2
 redcap_v14.3.0/home.php(20): require_once('/var/www/html/r...') #3 index.php(9):
 include('/var/www/html/r...') #4 {main} thrown
File: redcap_v14.3.0/Classes/RenderProjectList.php
Line: 827
```

Im trying to solve this issue, but neither `sudo apt-get install php-dom`, nor `sudo apt-get install php8.0-xml` works. Im using Ubuntu with apache2, mysql installed and REDCap installation successfully done. However when i try to access my "My Projects" Page i have this error.

I've tried too add the line `extension=dom.so` into my php.ini file, located at "etc/php/8.3/apache2", with no results...
I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install the PHP DOM extension: Based on your PHP version, use the appropriate command to install the DOM extension. For example, the commands would be similar to:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.3-xml
sudo apt-get install php8.3-dom
```